# Android Keystore password error "UnrecoverableKeyException"

Tags: java, android, security, android-keystore, forgot-password

I was trying to release another version of my app when I entered my keystore and alias password and had the error "UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key". People have said this means that the alias password is different to the keystore password; my alias password is different to the keystore password but I cannot change the alias password to be the same as the keystore password without the same error occurring. How can I do this?

Comment: The default configuration of JSSE doesn't support alias passwords at all, only keystore passwords.

Comment: @EJP this is the Android extension of the Java key store library which supports aliases.  It is used primarily for Android app signing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I wrote a script to crack my own password! Future tip: Save password hints (some password letters with the missing ones substituted by asterisks with enough visible letters to remember the password) in text files, on the cloud etc.